# Install Postgresql on a MacOs Yosemite

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install postgresql on a Yosemite based osX to work with Rails. 
I tried different things in vain :
 - brew.
 - postgre.app
 - the dmg downloaded directly from the postgresql site.

When I type which psql in a cli I have this:

```
psql is /usr/local/bin/psql
psql is /usr/local/bin/psql
psql is /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0/bin/psql
psql is /usr/local/bin/psql
```

If I launch foreman start I have this error:

```
10:54:47 worker.1 |     Is the server running locally and accepting
10:54:47 worker.1 |     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And if I type psql I have this error too:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Have you actually initialised and started the postgresql server?

Comment: I've did this as instructed by brew Caveats "launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist"

Comment: Did you get any errors at this point? Is there a postgresql process running? Anything in logs?

Comment: At first nothing happen, but if I retype the launch instruction I have this : "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Operation already in progress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing postgresql using [macports](https://www.macports.org/) works for me. You can download the installer and open a Terminal-window. Edit your .bashrc if you use bash, I use zsh so I edited .zshrc but the line is the same:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql94/bin:$PATH
```

Close and open a new Terminal-window and type

> sudo port selfupdate

and it will download all available macports-packages. When it is done you can install postgresql with

> sudo port install postgresql94-server

Change your path to match the version of postgresql you are using, mine is ver. 9.4. Ver. 9.5 is also available.

Make postgreql start when your machine boots by reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/138676/how-to-restart-postgres-on-os-x/498427) thread. This also explains how to initialize your database.

You can add your username to postgresql so it can create databases. This can be convenient for testing etc. while developing.

> PGUSER=postgres createuser your-username

Macport puts everything it installs in /opt, the db and config-files in /opt/local/var/db/postgresql94. Other configuration-files usually goes into /opt/local/etc.

Comment: I followed the instruction you gave me, but I have this error when I try to type posgres "postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable."

Comment: Did you try "sudo su postgres -c '/opt/local/lib/postgresqlXY/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresqlXY/defaultdb' " where XY is your postgresql-version?

Comment: When you 'sudo launchctl load -w ...' this will start postgresql on boot. So you can restart your mac after this step.

Comment: Well, actually no, I used brew instead because my coworker advised me to. The real problem was a missing host parameter in my database.yml

Answer (score 0):

I did not succeeded in trying to install postgresql through Mac Ports.
I cleaned up all postgresql installation and I tried again installing through brew and I still got error while running foreman start.

I had two errors, my configuration required postgresql 9.4 and I was installing the version 9.5.
Another error happened and I had to add the following line to my development configuration in  my database.yml. Which I think was the main issue.

```
host: localhost
```